# Why is List.remove overloaded the way it is?

Tags: java, api, list, collections

Is there historical reasons to the two ambiguous `List.remove`?

- [`List.remove(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29)
- [`List.remove(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)

It seems like terrible design to me.
For a `List<Integer>` it just seems really confusing.

EDIT:

Everybody seems pretty fine with this. Let me precise things a bit.

Let's say I have a `List<Boolean>`.

```
Integer idx = Integer.valueOf(2);
list.remove(idx)
```

Though `idx` is an object, Java compiles and will remove the item at index 2.

Now if it had been a `List<Integer>`, the very same code would have called a different method with a totally different behavior.

Let's not talk about what would happen with Generics.

I feel like **different behavior implies different names** is a precious rule, especially within the same class.

Comment: In case of `List<Integer>`, the appropriate way to remove an int in the list is to use `remove(Integer.valueOf(number))`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all:

- [`List.remove(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) removes *an element at the specified index* and
- [`List.remove(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) (or [`Collection.remove(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)) removes *the specified element*.

I'm not sure if this was already known, but for completeness sake, I thought I'd mention it.

An important part to notice is that the API predates generics (and more importantly) auto-boxing by quite a bit (the collections API was introduced in Java 1.2 and auto-boxing was introduced in Java 5).

So when they first designed the API, there was absolutely no way to confuse the two. Even if your `List` contained `Integer` objects, it's simple: if you call the method with a primitive argument type (`int`), then it's the index, if you pass in an `Object` (even if it's `Integer`), then you pass in the object to remove.

Granted, it's *still* not the greatest idea (but quite a few Java APIs are ... less than perfect), but the chance for confusion was much lower back then.

The increased chance of confusion only exists since the `int`/`Integer` barrier became less visible thanks to auto-boxing and auto-unboxing.

Sidenote: an important "feature" of the collections API is "short names for commonly used methods". The previous "solution" of [`Vector`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)/[`Enumeration`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) had notoriously long names for pretty common operations:

- `Vector.elementAt()` vs. `List.get()`
- `Vector.addElement()` vs. `Collection.add()`
- `Enumeration.hasMoreElements()`/`nextElement()` vs. `Iterator.hasNext()`/`next()`
- `Vector.removeElement()` vs. `Collection.remove()`
- `Vector.removeElementAt()` vs. `List.remove(int)`

And the last one are where they probably went *a bit too* far.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, this exact case is frequently cited as an example of how perfectly well-intentioned language changes (generics, autoboxing) can combine with each other and with existing APIs to produce bugs. Indeed Josh wishes he had given the methods different names, but when that interface was first created, it was never imagined that there could be any conflict between an Object and an int. You can find an exploration of this issue in Java Puzzlers (Bloch/Gafter).

Answer (score 0):

What, this is not ambigious at all. One removes at a specified index, the other removes an object where-ever it is first  found in the list... oO

EDIT - the definition of a method is more than just the name.  The type and number of arguments is part of the definition.  When you take the *entire* method definition, there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @poulejapon, First, im flagging your comment for insults.  Second, having multiple methods with different argument/argument-types is a standard OO practice.  The ambiguity is resolved by looking at the arguments.

Comment: Sorry if you got offended. I think using polymorphism with different argument/argument-types is indeed a standard OO practice but ONLY when they have the same meaning. Here the behavior is way to different.

Answer (score 0):

One of them is for removing from specific index

The other is removing an object, index is not important.

Comment: Ambiguity is precisely when two different things have the same name.

Comment: it has nothing to do with design, just bad naming you may say then.

Comment: @fmucar: naming *is* a pretty important part of API design, I'd say. `Collection` wouldn't be the same thing if I'd had been called `ThingThatHoldsMultiplesOfOtherThings`.

Comment: I never said it is not important, if you call Collection as ThingThatHoldsMultiplesOfOtherThings thats your fault, not design flaw/fault.

Comment: You can call it objectCollection, collectionOfObjects, objects, objectList, objectSet... this is not design but it is coding convention. It is developer responsibility to give good names not designers/architects. So what i tried to say is, naming may be bad yes. instead of remove(int) maybe it should have been called as removeAtIndex(int)  or something which will make easier to understand.

Comment: @fmucar: you said that it's a naming problem and not a design problem. I argue that a naming problem **is** a design problem. And you seem to agree, because your proposed change is "just" a naming change.

Comment: I agree name could be a better name but I dont think naming is part of design, it is a convention. Design of a software may be very good but naming may not be. They are seperate things.

Comment: very normal, thats why i said it is subjective.

Answer (score -3):

How is this ambiguous? The documentation of each method seems clear to me:

> `E remove(int index)`
>   Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional operation).
>
> `boolean remove(Object o)`
>   Removes the first occurrence in this list of the specified element (optional operation). If this list does not contain the element, it is unchanged.

They do two completely different things, hence a need for both.

Comment: Yes I need both, but I wish they had different names ( removeAt? removeValue?  )